# Are tag badges bugged on beta sites?

Tags: support, tags, badges

I was looking at [Larian](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/386/larian-lequella)'s profile and noticed he had the Great Answer badge. This is, of course, is at least 100 upvotes. That alone qualifies you for a bronze badge in whatever tags are on that question. Yet, I don't see him having the badges for those tags.

In fact, only one bronze badge for tags has been awarded, despite having 13 users with 3k+ rep.

As a moderator on another (much younger) SE beta site, this is a big concern for me. Can anyone help shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There need to be at least 100 questions in that tag before any tag badges are awarded. You also need a minimum number of answers, 20 for the bronze badge, so you can't earn the badge if you only have one highly upvoted answer.

From the [tag badges description](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags):

> These badges are awarded for
>   participating in non community-wiki
>   questions with particular tags. If
>   enough votes are earned in a tag with
>   100+ total questions, the badge will
>   be automatically created and awarded.
>
> **Gold Tag Badge:** 
>   You must have a total
>   score of 1000 in at least 200
>   non-community wiki answers to achieve
>   this badge.
>
> **Silver Tag Badge:** You must have a
>   total score of 400 in at least 80
>   non-community wiki answers to achieve
>   this badge.
>
> **Bronze Tag Badge:** You must have a
>   total score of 100 in at least 20
>   non-community wiki answers to achieve
>   this badge.

Comment: Wow, a serious case of RTFM. I'm not entirely sure how I glazed over that, but thanks for pointing out the relevant information!

Comment: @glowcoder: It's really easy to miss.

Comment: @glowchowder Wow, I am mentioned in a Meta post!  *blush*  And don't feel bad about missing a lot of RTFM stuff.  They seem to hide away a lot of the finer details on many items here.  I thought for sure I had the generalist silver badge, only to find out that each and every of the top 40 tags needs to have 300 questions in it...  The documentation on the badges seems to be spread out a bit.  :)  Not that I mind, I'll get there eventually if I keep up here.

Comment: @Larian You're [also mentioned in a Stackoverflow blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) by Jeff Atwood ;-)